# Negative testing using the Rest API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to get a direct credit card payment declined through the rest api but no matter the amount I send, I always get the transaction approved. I read in the classic API docs that by sending 105.39 as the amount total I could force the api to decline the payment, but all I'm getting is a INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR response when I do this.

So the question is: how do I get the rest api (sandbox) to decline a direct credit card payment?

Comment: For mocks you could also give [vREST](http://vrest.io) a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The developer sandbox is very forgiving, and will usually accept just about anything (yes, this is less than ideal).  I'd recommend just trying a bad card number in live (4111 1111 1111 1111 comes to mind).  Don't do it too many times in a row, however, or PayPal will start throttling your requests.

If you're really just looking for a mocked endpoint that returns canned errors, I'd try [mockable](http://www.mockable.io/).

Comment: Yep, I'm affraid that's our only option atm. Thanks!